# Ratio of areas of two triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Based on the figure below, what is the ratio of the area of triangle $CGI$ to the area of triangle $ABC$, in terms of $\theta$?

[image: What is the ratio of the area of triangle $CGI$ to the area of triangle $ABC$, in terms of $\theta$?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the right triangles in the picture are similar, so (noting $|BG|=|BD|$)

$$\begin{align}
\frac{|\triangle CIG|}{|\triangle ABC|} &= \left(\frac{|CG|}{|AC|}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{|BC|-|BG|}{|AC|}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{|BC|-|BD|}{|AC|}\right)^2 \\
&= \left(\frac{|BC|\left(1-\sin\theta\right)}{|AC|}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{|BC|}{|AC|}\right)^2\left(1-\sin\theta\right)^2 \\
&= \tan^2\theta \left(1-\sin\theta\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

Fixing $AC$ at length $1$, $\dfrac{\text{Area}(CGI)}{\text{Area}(ABC)}$ is seen to be $\dfrac{\left ( {\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}} - \sin(\theta)\tan(\theta)\right )^2 \tan(\theta)}{\sin(\theta) \left (\cos(\theta)+ \sin(\theta)\tan(\theta) \right)}$. Mathematica simplifies this ratio to $(\sin(\theta)-1)^2\tan^2(\theta)$.

[image: What is the ratio of the area of triangle $CGI$ to the area of triangle $ABC$, in terms of $\theta$?]

Comment: To whomever down-voted this answer: can you explain why you down-voted?

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica isn’t needed for the simplification, which is quite straightforward:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\left({\sin\theta \over \cos\theta} - \sin\theta\tan\theta\right)^2 \tan\theta}{\sin\theta\big(\cos\theta+\sin\theta\tan\theta\big)}&=\frac{\left(\tan\theta-\sin\theta\tan\theta\right)^2\tan\theta}{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\left(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{\tan^3\theta(1-\sin\theta)^2}{\tan\theta}\\\\
&=\tan^2\theta(1-\sin\theta)^2\;.
\end{align*}$$